# Django filter queryset in template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm still studying in school and still new in Python language & Django framework and I'm trying doing projects to learn the best practice for it.

Right now I'm building a project like following :

- Topics Model => which is user can write a new topic
- Replies Model => which is user can write a new reply for a specific topic
- Likes Model => which is user can vote up or down for a topic or reply

it's a little bit close from stackoverflow site .

Models.py

```
class Topic(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length=400)
like = models.IntegerField(default=0)
dislike = models.IntegerField(default=0)
image = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)
created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title[0:51]



class Reply(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
reply = models.TextField()
created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def likes(self):
    return Likes.objects.filter(reply=self, reply_flag=1).count()
    likes.short_description = 'likes'

def dislikes(self):
    return Likes.objects.filter(reply=self, reply_flag=-1).count()
    dislikes.short_description = 'dislikes'

def __str__(self):
    return self.reply



class Likes(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
reply = models.ForeignKey(Reply, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
reply_flag = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=(
('0', 'No'), ('1', 'Positive'), ('-1', 'Negative')))  # 1 = vote up , -1 vote down
```

Views.py

```
# get all topics 
def Topics(request):
topics = models.Topic.objects.all()
return render(request, 'Topics.html', {'topics': topics})



# get detail of specific topic
def TopicDetails(request, topic_id):
topic = get_object_or_404(models.Topic, pk=topic_id)
return render(request, 'Topic_Details.html', {'topic': topic, 'Likse': models.Likes.objects.all})
```

Templates:

topics.html :

```
 {% for topic in topics %}

   {% if topic.image}
      <img src="{{topic.image.url}}"
   {% endif %}
   title : {{ topic.title }}
   by : {{ topic.user }}
   total agree : {{ topic.like }}
   total not agree : {{ topic.dislike }}

{% endfor %}
```

topic.html :

```
 topic title : {{ topic.title }}

 {% for reply in topic.reply_set.all %}

   reply : {{ topic.reply }}
   by : {{ reply.user }}
   total agree : {% for like in reply.lieks_set.all %} {% if like.reply == reply and like.reply_flag == '1' %} <!-- should be total of vote up --> {% endif %} {%endfor %}
   total not agree : {% for like in reply.lieks_set.all %} {% if like.reply == reply and like.reply_flag == '-1' %} <!-- should be total of vote down --> {% endif %} {%endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

I faced an issue with filter likes based on reply, user and reply flag (vote up, vote down) in topic.html, 
 I have two questions :

- As my knowledge and as I read after search I couldn't filter data in template, So how could I show the filtered data in template based on reply, user and reply flag (vote up, vote down) ?
- Is structure of app is correct ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should definitely make use of generic views (like `DetailView` or `TemplateView`). You have couple of options on how to include proper information, decide which is simpler for you:

1. Override a `get_context` of a generic view (and include aggregates in a template variable)
2. Override `get_queryset` of a view (inluding aggregates in a query)
3. Create a custom model manager and include appropriate aggregates in a queryset.

See `aggregate` and `annotate` for more information on how to count or sum dependent models.